# CSS distinguishing styling within input[type=text]

Tags: html, css

I have a few `input[type=text]` fields, which I would like to customize in a different way.

I have got to know, that we can apply our styling even for the `name` property.

[Can I apply a CSS style to an element name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468766/can-i-apply-a-css-style-to-an-element-name)

Unfortunately, it doesn't work in my case.

My code looks like this:

```css
fig input[type=text]
        {
            width: 250px;
            min-width: 100px;
            padding: 12px 20px;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            outline: none;
            border: 1px solid #f7fbff;
            background-color: #f7fbff;
            display: inline-block; 
        }
```

```html
             <figure class="fig">
            <input type="text" name="riser_cupboard_key_type" 
                                                    pattern="[A-Za-z].{4,}" 
                                                    title="The text should include at least 4 
            letters" placeholder="Enter your answer" required>
         </figure>
```

All thhe options beloe weren't working

```
 .fig input[type=text] > input[name="riser_cupboard_key_type"] {
    width: 600px;
 }

 .fig input[type=text]  input[name="riser_cupboard_key_type"] {
    width: 600px;
 }

 .fig input[name="riser_cupboard_key_type"] {
    width: 600px;
 }
```

How can I make only this specified input different than others?

Comment: Well, your code works for me. Maybe you have nested the input in some other elements in your original code. If that is the case please share entire code.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340737/specify-multiple-attribute-selectors-in-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```css
.fig input[type=text][name="riser_cupboard_key_type"] {
    width: 600px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly fine, You can use any attribute available to make it unique, There shouldn't be any space between attributes.

```css
 .fig input[name="riser_cupboard_key_type"][placeholder="Enter your answer"] {
    width:400px;
    height: 2em;
    border: 2px solid crimson;
    border-radius: 3px;
 }
```

```html
 <figure class="fig">
  <input type="text" name="riser_cupboard_key_type" 
   pattern="[A-Za-z].{4,}" 
   title="The text should include at least 4 letters" 
   placeholder="Enter your answer" 
   required>
</figure>
```